# Is there a way to overwrite context parameters in dialogflow session through webhook?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I need to manually change a parameter in **Generic** context in the dialogflow session. My agent picks up a dog's name as parameter- `dog_name`. The name can be modified later which is stored as `dog_name_new`. So I need to manually update `dog_name` to `dog_name_new`. How might I be able to accomplish this?

Comment: could you explain it more clearly with screenshots of the intents and parameters?

Comment: you are taking `dog_name` from entity or context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can update the parameters for a context by re-sending the context as part of your fulfillment, but including the new values instead of the previous one.